# how to execute server application method in C#

Tags: c#, rmi

I have a client application and server application.
I wont to execute server application method using client application. such as RMI in java.
How can i do that in c# ?

Comment: Why not expose the method through [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)? Also see [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833550/send-code-to-be-executed-on-server-in-c-sharp-like-java-rmi).

Comment: yes.thank your comment.i did that with WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call Remote methods and events in C#.[**Here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4938/Remote-methods-and-events-in-C) you can find better tutorial to do that.

But better to use WCF to expose service layer to do that.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857%28vs.80%29.aspx)

> .NET Remoting based applications to the Windows Communication
>   Foundation to take advantage of the
>   new infrastructure for the creation of service oriented applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an easy to use WCF-like framework that can be used with .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET 5.0 you are welcome to check out [Zerto.WebApi.Rpc](https://github.com/ZertoPublic/Zerto.WebApi.Rpc).
You define the services using C# interfaces, and behind the scenes it will use HTTP and JSON (using ASP.NET Core).